# Brownian motion & Wiener Process

Tags: stochastic-processes

First of all, I keep on finding different answers to this question: Is Brownian motion (BM) process the same as Wiener process?or the Standard BM is Wiener?

My second question is about the integral of a BM. If a BM process is the input of an integral system, what is the autocorrelation of the output? 
$Z=\int_{0}^{t}B(s)ds,t>=0 $
Is Z a stationary process? Is Z ergodic?

Answer (score 1):

**First Question**

In mathematics, the Wiener process is a continuous-time stochastic process named in honor of Norbert Wiener. It is often called standard Brownian motion ,$\,B(0)=0\,$, after Robert Brown.

**Second Question**

Let $\{W_t\}_{t\ge 0}$, be a Wiener process (Standard Brownian motion). By application of Ito's lemma,  we have
$$
d(tW_t) = W_t dt + tdW_t+\underbrace{d[t\,,\,W_t]}_{0}\tag 1
$$
thus
$$
\int_0^t W_s ds = tW_t -\int_0^t sdW_s \tag{2}= \int_0^t (t-s)dW_s
$$
Thus ,by definition of [Ito's integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus), we can say $Z_t=\int_0^t W_s ds=\int_0^t (t-s)dW_s$ is a normal process, such that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t W_s ds\right] = 0\tag 3 
$$
on the other hand
\begin{align}
& \text{Cov}\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)=E\left[\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right]\tag 4
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
& \text{Cov}\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}\mathbb{E}\,[W_uW_v]\,\,du\,dv\tag 5
\end{align}
Since $\mathbb{E}\,[W_uW_v]=\min \{\,u\,,v \}$ therefor
\begin{align}
& \text{Cov}\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}\min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv\tag 6
\end{align}
For the case $s<t$

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}\min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv=\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{s}\min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv+\int_{0}^{s}\int_{s}^{t}\min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv\tag 7
\end{align}
we immediately have
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}\min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv=\frac{1}{3}s^3+\frac{1}{2}(t-s)s^2\tag 8
\end{align}
Following the same steps as described above, for the case $s > t$ we can also
 show
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{s}\int_{0}^{t}\min \{\,u\,,v \}\,\,du\,dv=\frac{1}{3}t^3+\frac{1}{2}(s-t)s^2\tag 9
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}\left(\int_{0}^{s}W_u\,du\,\,,\,\int_{0}^{t}W_v\,dv\right)=\frac{1}{3}\min\{s^3\,\,,t^3\}+\frac{1}{2}|t-s|\min\{s^2\,\,,t^2\}\tag {10}
\end{align}
$\text{Cov}(Z_t,Z_s)$ is not the function of $t-s$ thus $Z_t$ is not a stationary process.
it is clear
$$\text{Var}(Z_t)=\text{Cov}(Z_t,Z_t)=\frac 13 t^3$$
thus, the  autocorrelation between times $s$ and $t$ is
$$R(s,t)=\frac{\min\{s^3\,\,,t^3\}+\frac{3}{2}|t-s|\min\{s^2\,\,,t^2\}}{ts\sqrt{ts}}\tag {11}$$

Comment: First of all, Thanks a lot for your answer. unfortunately, in my second question I have never mentioned it to be a standard Brownian motion. I have found this answer you have given me before on math StackExchange. But if a standard BM is a Wiener then this is not the answer to my question. Also, my 2nd question included a part about ergodicity of Z? If someone could please kindly answer that too, I would appreciate it.  @BehrouzMaleki

Comment: Why do people vote for this answer? This is not the answer, the input is a Brownian Motion (BM), not a Standard BM... Can someone answer my question please?

Comment: @ Tayebe let  $W_0\ne 0$ . Set $W_0=x$, All of equations hold.